# VLOOKUP involving two books 1 & 2 to match column A values presence using vba with code in book3

Tags: vba, excel

I am using `VLOOKUP` for two books namely  Book1 and Book2 to check if value in  column `A`  of book1 is present in column `A`  of book 2 using VBA while code exists in book3.

```
Dim lookFor As Range, srchRange As Range, l As Integer

Set srchRange = Book2.Sheets("y").Range("A2:A" & yy)

For l = 2 To rowzz

    Set lookFor = Book1.Sheets("Only y").Range("A" & l)

    Sheets("Only y").Range("E" & l).Formula = _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookFor, _
         srchRange, 1, False

Next l
```

Comment: above code stops working minute first missing value is encountered.

Comment: Remove the `WorkSheetFunction.`

Comment: @Scott Thanks ! It solved the error.

Comment: wasn't it the missing bracket after `False`?  @ScottCraner: is there a `VLookup` method of the `Application` object?

Comment: @user3598756 yes, Using the WorksheetFunction will cause the code to stop on any error.  Just the Application.Vlookup() will allow that error to be passed to the variable or range in this case.  As long as the variable is declared as a variant, which a range is by default.

Comment: @ScottCraner: thanks but I couldn't (now I'm off my PC) get VLookup from intellisense after dotting Application. Maybe it was a lazy moment of it... As for the Variant: it's not passed to a Range but to a Formula but I guess it's a Variant as well.

Comment: @user3598756 it will not come up with intellisense but it does work.  Also the above code even though it is saying `.formula` it is passing the value of the vlookup not the formula into the range.  A range is of the type variant, so it can hold string and double and date and integer.  That is why when assigning a full range directly to an array variable the variable must be of the variant type. Otherwise a loop is needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner: thanks again. Always something new (and sometimes a bit strange) to learn every day.